# Like system using laravel and ajax Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, error-handling

I am encountering a 500 error in my Laravel AJAX-like system, and I am seeking assistance to resolve this issue. When I click the like button, it triggers the likeIconClicked() function, which sends an AJAX request to the server. The request is intended to perform the like action and update the icon accordingly. However, instead of the expected behavior, I received a 500 error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfVpb.png)

I have checked that the AJAX request parameters, such as the content ID, are correctly sent to the Laravel route. Additionally, I have verified that the route is properly defined and that the CSRF token is included in the request headers. Despite these confirmations, the issue persists. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me troubleshoot and resolve this error. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
for the button

```
<button onclick="likeIconClicked()" id="like-icon">
```

js

```
function likeIconClicked() {
           
  // Envoyer une requête AJAX au serveur pour effectuer l'action de like
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ route('like', $resultat->code) }}' ,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
    success: function(response) {

      // Changer la couleur de l'icône en fonction de la réponse du serveur
      if (response.liked) {
        // L'utilisateur a aimé, donc ajouter la classe CSS pour la couleur rouge
        $('#like-icon').addClass('liked');
      } else {
        // L'utilisateur a annulé son like, donc supprimer la classe CSS pour la couleur rouge
        $('#like-icon').removeClass('liked');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      // Gérer les erreurs de la requête
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

controller

```
 public function like($code)
    {
        $annonce=Annonce::findorfail($code);
        $user=Auth::user();
        if($user->hasLiked($annonce)){
            $user->unlike($annonce);
            $bol=false;
        }
        else{
            $user->like($annonce);
            $bol=true;
        }
        
        return response()->json([
            'liked' => $bol,
        ]);
    }
```

route

```
Route::post('/like/{code}', 'App\Http\Controllers\AnnonceController@like')->name('like');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... have you made sure that `$resultat->code` is not `null`? also i would explicitly define the key to make sure it is taking the parameter: `route('like', ['code' => $resultat->code])` ..... on a site note, you should check the server logs for what is causing the 500 error instead of guessing

Comment: Thank you for your response! I followed your suggestion and used the URL {{ route('like', ['code' => $resultat->code]) }}. Additionally, after investigating the error logs in the laravel.log file, I discovered that the issue stemmed from the 'annonce_id' column being set to null when inserting data into the 'likes' table. I went ahead and fixed the method in my User model to ensure the proper assignment of 'annonce_id'.I'm happy to share that it worked! The error is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code:

```js
url: '{{ route('like', $resultat->code) }}'
```

With this code:

```js
url: '{{ route('like', [$resultat->code]) }}'
```

OR this Code

```js
url: "{{ route('like') }}" + '/' + $resultat->code,
```